# Data Sampling based on a field

Tags: java, mysql, statistics, sampling

I want to sample data based on a timestamp field. I am reading huge data files, each having close to million record a day. I have several such files for every month.

Now I want to read this data, but store, say, only 5% or 10% into a mysql database. I do not have prior knowledge of number of records in each of the data files.

Is there any way with which I can sample only 5% of total read data for a file? Are there any standard statistical approaches to this kind of problem?

**EDIT based on comments below:**

Before this sampling idea, I had created a key based partition and index on two fields: id and date. The id field is more like a clientId. Even with partitioning, a group by 2 fields on 15 million rows would take criminally long time, in the range of 30-60 mins. I had also created and additional index on one of the group by field.

My explanation would show this:

> SIMPLE visits  ref 3ColumnerIndex,2ColumnIndex 2ColumnIndex    302 const   7493642 Using where; Using filesort

Got this performance after giving innodb a buffer size of 4 GB!

Comment: In the file, is each record on its own line or contained in some way?

Comment: yes, each record is a line. and i read that file in my java code and do cleaning, parsing etc. Which is not a problem, i can read all of it and can even write all of it to database, but writing all of data for a months gets me to close to 15-20 million records.

Comment: So, after reading the file, do you know how many records you read?

Comment: isn't this a statistics question?? :) You might need to eval your data to know how you should collect your sample, your you could have a bad sample that doesn't correspond to the total data

Comment: nope, i read one line at a time. after reading one line, i need to make a decision weather to write it to the db based on my sample size

Comment: @RaviBhatt: Then I would recommend analyzing all of your data as you read it and storing the analysis result in the database.

Comment: @ismaelga yes, indeed. its a statistics question, wanted to know if there are any known methods/algorithms.

Comment: Depending on your hardware and query requirements, 15-20 million records/month isn't that serious. RANGE partition by date, e.g. monthly, and judiciously apply indices. If this still causes too much IO for queries, consider aggregating into daily/weekly/monthly rollup either in the database or maybe in code before writing into the database, i.e. only write 1 record per hour or day into the database if you can live with that granularity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an estimate of the number of records for this to work, but if you don't have strict requirements of how many samples you need this shouldn't be a problem:

1. Suppose you are choosing `k` samples from `n` records.
2. For each record, or until you have enough records:

   1. Produce a random number between 0 and 1.
   2. If it is less than `k/n`, output the current record. Put `k := k-1` and `n := n-1`.
   3. Else, discard the record and put `n := n-1`.

Each record appear in the output with probability k/n. E.g. the probability of the second record appearing would be:

```
(k/n)*(k-1)/(n-1) + ((n-k)/n)*k/(n-1) = (k-1+n-k)*k/(n*(n-1)) = k/n
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i see how this woild work. i do not have n beforehand.

Comment: You can "guesstimate" n and k as a fraction of the size of the input file. If you get it wrong either some records have less probability of getting selected than others, or you get fewer than k records of output. Based on your requirement of producing a random sample of 5-10% this should be OK.

Comment: Another thing you can do is compare the generated random number to a constant percentage, but then the number of output records has some randomness. Or you can use this algorithm for selecting, say, 500 records out of each block of 10000, but then the output has got some bias due to some combinations being more probable than others.

Comment: i agree, was thinking in terms of file size. Thanks, this should be enough for now :-)

Answer (score -1):

You could use Limit like

```
SELECT name, email FROM users WHERE name LIKE 'a%' LIMIT 10;
```

but I also found this link which might help you more specifically

http://www.gloomy.eu/mysql-desired-percentage-of-rows/

Comment: This will only return the first N records of a query, defined by some semi-random database ordering. This is far from sampling.